# Using polymorphism or Interfaces in C# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, polymorphism

In my game in unity C#, I have two classes one is a `PlayerHealth` and the other is `EnemyHealth` they have the same functions but these two fields are inverted `currentHapinessPower` and `currentSadnesPower`.
I don't know if i should use the polymorphism principle or inheritance or interfaces.

These are the classes:

```
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Public Instances
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject Pl_DeathParticle;

    public TextMeshProUGUI NumOfHappyPower;
    public TextMeshProUGUI NumOfSadPower;
    #endregion

    #region HapAndSad System Variables
    public int playerHappinessPower;
    [HideInInspector] public int currentHappinessPower; <--
    [HideInInspector] public int currentSadnesPower;    <--These two
    #endregion

    #region HapAndSad States
    private bool isSad = false;
    #endregion

    void Start()
    {
        currentHappinessPower = playerHappinessPower; // in the enemy class is currentSadnessPower
        NumOfSadPower.enabled = false; // here in the enemy class is true
    }

    void Update()
    {
        HapAndSadPowerSystem();
        StartCoroutine(CheckThePlayerSadState());
    }

    void HapAndSadPowerSystem()
    {
        if (currentHappinessPower > 0) //enemy class: currentSadnessPower
        {
            NumOfHappyPower.text = currentHappinessPower.ToString(); //also here is changed
        }

        else if (currentHappinessPower == 0) // here also is currentSadnessPower
        {
            NumOfHappyPower.enabled = false;
            NumOfSadPower.enabled = true;

        }

        else if (currentHappinessPower < 0 && currentSadnesPower == 0) //and here
        {
            isSad = true;  // enemy class is false                                                                  
            currentSadnesPower = currentHappinessPower * -1; //Make the rest of the soubstraction positive / also here its inverted
            NumOfHappyPower.enabled = false; //true in the enemy class
            NumOfSadPower.enabled = true; // false
            NumOfSadPower.text = currentSadnesPower.ToString();
        }

        else if (currentSadnesPower > 0)
        {
            NumOfSadPower.text = currentSadnesPower.ToString();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CheckThePlayerSadState()
    {
        if (isSad == true) //here is false
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            GameObject PlayerDeath_particle_prefab = Instantiate(Pl_DeathParticle, Player.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            Destroy(PlayerDeath_particle_prefab.gameObject, 1f);
            Destroy(Player.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the enemy class:

```
public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour

    #region Public Instances
    public GameObject Enemy;
    public GameObject En_DeathParticle;

    public TextMeshProUGUI NumOfHappyPower;
    public TextMeshProUGUI NumOfSadPower;
    #endregion

    #region HapAndSad System Variables
    public int enemySadnesPower;
    [HideInInspector] public int currentHappinessPower;
    [HideInInspector] public int currentSadnesPower;
    #endregion

    #region HapAndSad States
    private bool isSad = true;
    #endregion

    void Start()
    {
        currentSadnesPower = enemySadnesPower;
        NumOfHappyPower.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        HapAndSadPowerSystem();
        StartCoroutine(CheckThePlayerSadState());
    }

    void HapAndSadPowerSystem()
    {
        if (currentSadnesPower > 0)
        {
            NumOfSadPower.text = currentSadnesPower.ToString();
        }

        else if (currentSadnesPower == 0)
        {
            NumOfHappyPower.enabled = true;
            NumOfSadPower.enabled = false;

        }

        else if (currentSadnesPower < 0 && currentHappinessPower == 0)
        {
            isSad = false;
            currentHappinessPower = currentSadnesPower * -1;
            NumOfHappyPower.enabled = true;
            NumOfSadPower.enabled = false;
            NumOfHappyPower.text = currentHappinessPower.ToString();
        }

        else if (currentHappinessPower > 0)
        {
            NumOfHappyPower.text = currentHappinessPower.ToString();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CheckThePlayerSadState()
    {
        if (isSad == false)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            GameObject PlayerDeath_particle_prefab = Instantiate(En_DeathParticle, Enemy.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

            Destroy(PlayerDeath_particle_prefab.gameObject, 1f);
            Destroy(Enemy.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces are [less performant](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7291) than using abstract implementations/polymorphism.  The link provided only touches *some* of the reasons.  There are times to use interfaces and times to use inheritance but keep in mind that they are handled differently.

Answer (score 0):

These scripts are almost identical. I would use the same script as the player and the enemy. And add a boolean to distinguish between the player and the enemy.

Edit:
If you want to use inheritance or polymorphism desperately, I would recommend you to make an Entity class and make Player and Enemy derive from it.

Comment: Yes but should I use inheritance or polymorphism and how can you please explain.

Comment: Inheritance and polymorphism are terms that describe different things working together. It's not one or the other, it's one and the other. Inheritance to get data and actions fron base, polymorphism to implement specific subactions.

Comment: IMHO, treat all person objects in the environment the same. Do you want to expand to multiplayer at some point? But maybe add them to a "team" or "force" to tell friend from foe. The player doesn't need to be a specific class, but a static pointer to the "person" you are controlling.